# Create Re-Usable Data Object; Only Add On Iterations

Tags: c#, datatables

I want to create a data table class with specified columns that I can use for calling methods on, like copying or aggregating, where I can iterate over some records and add to the table.

I thought I could create the private and public variable sets and assign the value of the table to my defaults, like:

```
private DataTable newTable;
public DataTable NewTable
{
    get { return newTable; }
    set
    {
        DataTable newTable= new DT();
        newTable.Columns.Add("Name", typeof(string));
        newTable.Columns.Add("Id", typeof(int));
    }
}
```

My thought was that a person could get that table, but they couldn't set it because it is set to a default.  However, I'm seeing a message from the interface that this will always be null, even if I later use it in a method.

Another stab I took was creating a static class that I could use in a method, involving the above with a data table being set:

```
static DataTable myDt()
{
     DataTable myDt = new DT();  
     myDt.Columns.Add("Name", typeof(string));
     myDt.Columns.Add("Id", typeof(int));
}
```

This doesn't function the way I need on an iteration when someone is iterating over 100K records, I don't want a data table created each time; I want the data table created once with a definition, a data row created once, then on each iteration, data are added to a new row based on the column names from the definition.  My thought was that the class would have the data table definition, that would never change, and a data row that could be changed on each iteration and added to the table.

Based on what I'm trying to do, where am I going wrong, or is this even possible?

Comment: The initial problem is that the setter doesn't set the private variable, it just makes a new variable and then throws it away.  So the class-level `newTable` is always `null`.  But a more significant design problem here is that the setter doesn't actually set what it's given, which is going to be very misleading and will cause all sorts of logical errors that are difficult to debug over time.

Comment: `DataTable newTable= new DT();` is not the same DataTable as `private DataTable newTable;`. You're hiding the class-level DataTable with that variable in the `set`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to wrap a data table and only allow consuming code to add rows to it, then don't expose the data table at all.  Keep it private.  Something like this:

```
public class MyTableWrapper
{
    private DataTable table { get; set; }

    public MyTableWrapper()
    {
        table = new DataTable();
        table.Columns.Add("Name", typeof(string));
        table.Columns.Add("Id", typeof(int));
    }
}
```

Then to allow users to add a row, just expose a method for that:

```
public void AddRow(DataRow newRow)
{
    table.Rows.Add(newRow);
}
```

You may also want to put some error checking in the above method to validate that the provided `DataRow` matches the schema of the table.  If it doesn't, just throw an exception.

In fact, it would also be a good idea to expose a method to generate a row for consuming code:

```
public DataRow GetNewRow()
{
    return table.NewRow();
}
```

For any other functionality you may want to expose from the built-in `DataTable` class, just add more similar pass-through methods as needed.  The wrapper itself is very simple, all it needs is a private member of the type being wrapped and pass-through methods to expose just the functionality you want.